# Cannot copy to Bluemix container volume

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have created the volumes in my django-cms file share:

```
$ cf ic volume fs-list
Name                                   Size   IOPS/GB   Created               State   
8194062f-916d-49fa-8ae1-91ce92f5752a   20     4.00      2016-07-27 07:00:56   READY   
django-cms                             20     2.00      2016-10-06 17:21:26   READY   

$ cf ic volume list
django-cms-app-vol
django-cms-postgres-vol
```

The volume is associated with the container `djangocmsdocker_nginx_1` by means of this compose file and confirmed by the fact that `djangocmsdocker_nginx_1` has access to `/usr/src/app` below

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  # Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine 
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres 
  env_file: .env
  volumes:
    - ./web:/usr/src/app
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn mycms.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

So this is what I'm trying to do but Bluemix can't create the target directory structure ... is there a bug in Bluemix cf ic  or am I doing something wrong?

```
$ docker cp -L ./web/mycms djangocmsdocker_nginx_1:/usr/src/app/mycms
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): mkdir /mycms: permission denied
```

(BTW There is no tar file in `./web/mycms`)

#### I tried a few different things:

I look into the container. All looks OK. But I  `chmod` in case there's a permissions issue. And now I have:

```
$ cf ic exec -it djangocmsdocker_nginx_1 bash
root@instance-0090e170:/# cd /usr/src/app                                                                                                            
root@instance-0090e170:/usr/src/app# mkdir mycms
root@instance-0090e170:/usr/src/app# mkdir static
root@instance-0090e170:/usr/src/app# ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Oct  6 19:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct  6 18:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  6 19:09 mycms
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  6 19:09 static
root@instance-0090e170:/usr/src/app# exit
exit
```

But still I can't write to the volume. What's going on?

```
$ docker cp -L ./web/mycms/ djangocmsdocker_nginx_1:/usr/src/app/mycms/
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): mkdir /mycms: permission denied
```

#### More info

I am logged into Bluemix and Docker is configured to Bluemix containers as follows:

```
$ env | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net:8443
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/iainhouston/.ice/certs/containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net/8194062f-...
```

Note that I get the same error with `cf ic cp`.

I have the  correct permissions for the directory I'm copying. (Even though the reported error is apparently Bluemix's Docker server unable to create a directory in the volume. ... from a tar file?)

```
$ ls -la ./web
total 472
drwxr-xr-x   9 iainhouston  staff     306  4 Oct 10:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 iainhouston  staff     374  1 Oct 22:36 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 iainhouston  staff     210  6 Oct 10:17 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x   1 iainhouston  staff     248 23 Sep 21:11 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x   2 iainhouston  staff      68 23 Sep 21:11 media
drwxr-xr-x   9 iainhouston  staff     306 23 Sep 21:11 mycms
-rw-r--r--   1 iainhouston  staff  228352  4 Oct 10:14 project.db
-rw-r--r--   1 iainhouston  staff     694 23 Sep 23:39 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  12 iainhouston  staff     408 29 Sep 10:26 static

$ docker cp -L ./web djangocmsdocker_nginx_1:/usr/src/app
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): mkdir /web: permission denied

$ id
uid=501(iainhouston) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff), ...
$
```

#### Dockerfiles

`./web/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV BUILD_TIMESTAMP 2016-10-06T:10:15

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app
```

`./nginx/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM tutum/nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD sites-enabled/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please do a ls -la on the local directory (mycms) that you want to copy into the container volume and then retrieve the actual ID of the user that created it? It might be that the local directory was created with a user ID that is outside the accepted range inside the container and therefore cannot be mapped.

Also, I noticed that you are using `docker cp` instead of `cf ic cp`. Just to make sure, did you configure your CLI to run native Docker commands when you logged into the IBM Container service? If not, please try to use cf ic cp.

Thanks

Comment: Question updated as requested. Let me know if you need more / different.

Answer (score 0):

Took a shot at reproducing this as well, and I'm a bit baffled.  I was not able to get the error you're seeing, trying to figure out why.

First, some explanation:  the error is complaining about the TAR file because that's how `docker cp` works under the covers - it tars up the source file/directory, copies that over, then untars it at the destination.

Now, the error that it's giving seems important here.  Both of the errors are complaining about trying to create a directory off /, NOT off /usr/src/app.  I considered that there might be a link under there, but was unable to reproduce the failure in my testing.

Does not appear to be an issue with the local userid (I created a local userid/group matching yours for my testing, and it had no issues).  I see that inside `cf ic exec`, you're running as root - what id is the app inside the container running as? (basically, is there a USER directive in your Dockerfile)

Comment: `./web/Dockerfile` and `./nginx/Dockerfile` added to question

Comment: Yes, I too noticed failure to mkdir at  fs root directory. As requested: ./web/Dockerfile` and `./nginx/Dockerfile` added to question. See no `USER` directives.

Comment: @N Fritze  Please see what I am trying to achieve and how I am trying to achieve it - details of all files  [here](https://iainhouston.com/blog/docker-izing-django-cms.html)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately we are still not able to reproduce the problem. :-( Could you please try to copy one file/ the entire folder to another directory inside the container? Like, for example:

1. /usr/src
2. /usr/src/app/tmp (You might need to create the tmp folder first)
3. /var/tmp

we are interested to see if that will cause the same permission error.

Also, could you please provide us with the CLI output of `cf ic info` and the CF, Docker and Docker Compose version that you use?
Thanks a lot!
Thanks a lot. 
cf plugins (to see the IBM Containers

Comment: Well OK ... now things have changed. So, this time I got an error from `docker-compose -f docker-compose.bluemix.yml up -d`: *ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: Minimum memory limit allowed is 4MB*. So I removed both the `mem_limit` keys from `docker-compose.bluemix.yml` (Pretty sure I  copied `mem_limit` from a Bluemix docs example?). And **now** the copy has worked!